# Two string matching on date

Tags: java, android

Take a Date as a string and check another date also as a string. Then when I go to check the values is equal or not. then it returns false.

```
            String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());

            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, currentDateTimeString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            String date="14 Feb 2018";
            dateResult=currentDateTimeString.equals(date);

            if (dateResult==true){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "correct Date", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrong Date", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Debugging is your friend. Print out `currentDateTimeString` and see what it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

`DateFormat.getDateInstance()` will return a formatter that is based on the current locale. For me, with my phone set to `en-US`, I get this output:

```
Feb 13, 2018
```

If I change to `fr-FR`, I get this output instead:

```
13 févr. 2018
```

So it's quite possible that your `DateFormat.getDateInstance()` is returning a formatter that's creating different text than you expect.